# I installed Ubuntu only, not dual-boot. But now I can't find my drives

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, usb-installation

I recently clean installed Ubuntu without dual boot, so everything was erased, but now I can't seem to find where my C and D drives are located. 
Here are the results of some commands that I tried:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track , 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/0 size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifiers: 0x000cf109

Device     Boot        Start         End       Blocks    Id  Systems
/dev/sda1   *          2048       308457471  154227712   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         308459518       312580095   2060289     5  Extended
/dev/sda5         308459520       312580095   2060288    82 Linuxswap/Solaris

mount 
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw, errors = remount - ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec, nosuid, nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw, mode = 0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw, noexec, nosuid, gid = 5, mode = 0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec, nosuid, size = 10%, mode = 0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw, noexec, nosuid, nodev, size = 5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid, nodev, user = dangmanhtruong)

sudo lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN   RM      SIZE    RO    TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0      0     149.1G    0    disk    
--sda1              8:1      0     147.1G    0    part   /
--sda2              8:2      0         1K    0    part
--sda5              8:5      0         2G    0    part   [swap]
```

Please help me thank you very much

Comment: Your drives names in Linux are not C and D, they are sda1, sda2, sda5. You can start Disks from the dash and see it visually.

Comment: @lapisdecor from the dash? how ? I'm a total noob when it comes to Linux. And how do I access these drives ???

Comment: You just press the windows key on your keyboard ant type Disks. On Ubuntu I mean. You access your drives with the nautilus file manager wich is on the launchbar on the left. You can also type nautilus on the dash.

Comment: @lapisdecor I did, and there was only a single 160GB hard disk, with 3 partitions. How do i access them?

Comment: Disks is for partitioning the drive, close it and on the dash type help, and read it, it preety useful. Your files are the second icon from top on the lauchbar.

Comment: @lapisdecor so I just use them however I please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38512/discussion-between-lapisdecor-and-dang-manh-truong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `C:` partition and no `D:` partition anymore. As you said that you installed Ubuntu by choosing the option to use the whole disk for Ubuntu, of course the disk was erased completely.

The `C:` partition on which most probably the Windows operating system was located and the `D:` partition on which most probably your personal data was located before are gone forever.

Let's explain it as easy as possible to understand the difference ... your new disk layout now is :
`sda1` (formerly `C:`) used for `Ubuntu` and `sda2` / `sda5` (formerly `D:`) used for `linux-swap`

Comment: but how do i acces these sda1,sda2... ? I only see an enormous heap of memory and I'm to throw everything I want there, irrespective of these sda

Comment: @DangManhTruong : You are already using (access) these partitions when you boot the Ubuntu system. :)

Comment: very well I should get used to linux then